# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'Int'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I'm recently trying to build a custom UITableViewCell Class by adding a minor improved UITextField.
I am also coding in swift 2 and I realised this error by recompiling the project in Xcode 7 beta.
I initialised the array by call a custom init method.

Heres is my Code:

INIT METHOD

```
init(dataObject: [NSManagedObject]!, objectAttributeValues: [String]!,placeholder: String!, segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl?) {
    self.dataObject = dataObject
    self.Placeholder.text = placeholder
    self.objectAttributeValues = objectAttributeValues

    if segmentedControl != nil {
        self.segmentedControl = segmentedControl!
        didHaveSegmentedControl = true
    }
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

IBACTION EditingChanged

```
currentInputCount = "\(TextField.text)".characters.count
    var indexOfArray: Int = 0
    countOfRun = 0


    if currentInputCount == 0 {
        countOfRun = 0
        formerInputCount = 0
        editingDidEndForTextField = false
        concatenedWord = []
        Placeholder.text = ""
    }

    if !editingDidEndForTextField && currentInputCount > 0 {
        while countOfRun < dataObject.count {
            if !backspaceWasPressed() {
                var arrayOfCharacters: [String] = []
                if countOfRun <= dataObject.count - 1 {
                    for character in objectAttributeValues[countOfRun] {
                        let string = String(character)
                        arrayOfCharacters.append(string)
                    }
                }
                var convertedStringInFormOfArrayOfStrings: [String] = arrayOfCharacters
                if currentInputCount == 1 {
                    concatenedWord.append(convertedStringInFormOfArrayOfStrings[currentInputCount-1])
                }
                else if countOfRun > 0 {
                    if objectAttributeValues[countOfRun].characters.count != concatenedWord[countOfRun].characters.count {
                        concatenedWord[countOfRun] = concatenedWord[countOfRun] + convertedStringInFormOfArrayOfStrings[currentInputCount-1]
                    }
                }
                countOfRun += 1
            }
```

The error appears in line:

```
for character in objectAttributeValues[countOfRun] {
```

I have no clue what it could be...
Can anybody help me.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Swift 2, you can't simply loop over a `String` to enumerate the characters anymore, now you have to call the `characters` method on the String itself:

```
for letter in "hello".characters {
    print(letter)
}
```

So for you, given that `objectAttributeValues[countOfRun]` seems to return a String, that would be:

```
for character in objectAttributeValues[countOfRun].characters {
    ...
}
```

This is because `String` does not conform to `SequenceType` anymore in Swift 2.

Answer (score -4):

Like Eric said, as of Swift 2 you can no longer just go through a String like that.

In my opinion the easiest, and most likely the best programatically correct way to do this would be with a function.

so

```
func example(s: Int, str: String) -> Character {
   var count = 0
   for character in str {
       if(count == s)
          return character
       count++
   }
  return " "
}
```

Comment: You've turned a simple O(1) lookup into an O(n) lookup!